# Splitting dataframe into multiple dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 6 days. I want to split the dataframe for every 2 days and create new dataframe.How to do it ?. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your input in text format? Also, can you include the expected output for that input? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's treat your "filename" column as a datetime:

```
df["filename"] = pd.to_datetime(df["filename"])
```

Now, using [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) you can group your data by the frequency you want (2 days):

```
for _, df_2days in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="filename", freq="2D")):
    # Each `df_2days` object is a dataframe with only rows of a 2 days range
    print(df_2days)
```

If you want to unpack the values (assuming that you'll always receive 3 groups), you can do this:

```
(_, df1), (_, df2), (_, df3) = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="filename", freq="2D"))
```

The `_` variable is a common name for values that can be ignored (is a convention). Because each group is a tuple of index name and dataframe, and since you only want the dataframe, we can ignore the first value of each of the 3 tuples.

Comment: Thanks its working now. But I want to create new dataframe for every 2 days. For ex 
Df1 = 28th to 30 
Df2 = 1 to 2
etc. 

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Vinay_S updated my answer to include the syntax to achieve what you want

Comment: Hi , I got one more doubt.  Now I have data for 30 days.  How can I divide in 2 days and give it name df1, df2, df3 ---df15 automatically , instead of writing manually.

Comment: I think having 15 variables like that is not a good idea. You might benefit from a list of 15 dataframes maybe: `[df_i for (_, df_i) in df.groupby(...)]`